# General expression that represents a combined period of 2 sine functions

Tags: functions, trigonometry

How to find the general expression that represents the combined period of 
$y=5\sin(\pi x/6)$ and $y=3\sin(\pi x/4)$? what are the limitations of this model?

Comment: Do you mean "common period" ?

Comment: This look like an attempt to obtain a solution for a homework problem to me.

What model are you talking about? What have you tried by yourself so far?

Answer (score 2):

The period of sine function is $2\pi$, i.e.
$$
\forall y \in \mathbb{R} \quad \sin(y + 2\pi) = \sin (y)
$$
Now, apply this to your functions:

1. $
   5\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{6}\left(x+ T_1\right) \right) = 5\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{6}x \right) 
   \implies 
   \frac{\pi}{6}\left(x+ T_1\right)  = \frac{\pi}{6}x + 2\pi \implies T_1 = 12$
2. $
   3\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{4}\left(x+ T_2\right) \right) = 3\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{4}x \right) 
   \implies 
   \frac{\pi}{4}\left(x+ T_2\right)  = \frac{\pi}{4}x + 2\pi \implies T_2 = 8$

"*$T$ is the common* (combined?) *period*"  means that it is the smallest number such that
$$
\begin{cases}
5\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{6}\left(x+ T\right) \right) = 5\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{6}x \right)
\\
3\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{4}\left(x+ T\right) \right) = 3\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{4}x \right)
\end{cases}
\implies 
\begin{cases}
T = mT_1 = 12m, & m\in\mathbb{N}
\\
T = nT_2= 8n, & n\in\mathbb{N},
\end{cases}
$$
i.e. $ T$ is the **least common multiple** of $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Therefore we conclude that 
$$T = \operatorname{lcm}(12,8) = 24.$$